# Are questions about game specific bugs off topic?

Tags: support, specific-question

I frequent the [destiny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destiny) tag, and while browsing recent questions I came across

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198220/destiny-compatibility-pack-download-stops-at-50

I was going to flag it for closure, but could not find a good fit for it. The question is basically reporting a bug without asking a question. While the clear implication is how to recover from it, or move past it, this questions seems to be best placed at the bungie support forum than at gaming.stackexchange.com.

It didn't seem to exactly fit into any of the scenarios outlined by [@Raven Dreamer♦'s answer here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2102/25404). The closest one was

> "I triggered bug X, what does this mean for my game? / can I still do/get Y?"

So, is this question off topic, and if so what is the proper closure reason. If not, an explanation?

Comment: It's now closed as off-topic.